# How to make all blockquote having same height?

Tags: html, css

Thanks for stopping by. I was trying to make all my blockquote same height. As you can see my word was begin cut off after added `overflow:hidden`. I can't seem to find a good solution to fix it. Can any of you help?

Ps: Sorry for the misleading title of my question what I am trying to do is actually give all the blockquote having the same height. Not text align in div center.

```css
blockquote {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}

blockquote:before {
  color: #000;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.10em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}

blockquote:after {
  color: #000;
  content: close-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}

blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Person 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Nam quis nisl lorem. Sed vulputate, ipsum id vulputate placerat, ante ante tempor orci, a pulvinar dolor enim et felis. Aliquam at sapien arcu.</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Person 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Vivamus eu enim dolor. Donec sed nulla ligula. Etiam maximus diam vel felis aliquet, a placerat magna euismod. In pellentesque elit lorem, vel dictum mauris blandit at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
          ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Person 3</p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using height 100px and also overflow hidden that is the reason it cut off. Remove height 100px.

Comment: @KamranJabbar Hi, I just updated my question there. Sorry for the misleading question title.

Comment: @R3y I just want to know you want same height only? you already did it, is it? jsut remove 'line-height: 100px' then you will see all text

Comment: @Anami Hmm, is something like I want to give all my blockquote like for example height:300px; and no matter how short or long was my content is, the height will still the same. I did just add 'line-height: 100px', but the gap between the content spacing was too far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I linked the quotes to the paragraph instead of to the `blockquote`. Than I made the `blockquote` a flexbox, removed the line-height, changed the height to 120px for block 3 to fit and centered the content both horizontally and vertically.

```css
blockquote {
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}

blockquote p:before {
  color: #000;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.10em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}

blockquote p:after {
  color: #000;
  content: close-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.10em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}

blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Person 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Nam quis nisl lorem. Sed vulputate, ipsum id vulputate placerat, ante ante tempor orci, a pulvinar dolor enim et felis. Aliquam at sapien arcu.</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Person 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <blockquote>
        <p>Vivamus eu enim dolor. Donec sed nulla ligula. Etiam maximus diam vel felis aliquet, a placerat magna euismod. In pellentesque elit lorem, vel dictum mauris blandit at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
          ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Person 3</p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, your answer is nearly what I am trying to do. But it was not responsive at the smaller screen (for the long content, the content was outside the blockquote). Do you have any idea?

Comment: The height of the blockquote is limited to 120 pixels. I don't know if you did set a height on purpose. If the height is not required, just let me know. You can remove it without consequences which will likely make it responsive.

Comment: All right, I get it. Just limit my content then problem fix. I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

- `position: absolute`: Sets the position according to margins and inside the parent element
- `top` and `left`: Set margin from the top and the left to 50%, but make text or divs starting from the center of the outer element not visible
- `transform`: Transforms the iner object up and right to 50% of its height and width

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Why this code would fix the problem.

Comment: 1) position absolute - it will set position according to margins and inside the parent element 2) top and left - set margin from top and left to 50% but it will show out text or object starting from center of outer element so 3) we transform our inner object to up and right to 50% of its height and width

Comment: @Atam_JeetSingh please embed all the explanations and information in the answer itself (you can find the "edit" button), do not spread code and comments around, it's more difficult for other users to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `text-center` class in html tags while css is not written.

```
.text-center{
    text-align:center;
}
```

It should be working fine

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question there. Sorry for the misleading question title.

Comment: Ok for that you need to set min-height and max-height for `blackquote`

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is about setting max content's height to others, do refer below link which talks about different methods to set same height.

http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways